# Create Database : No Privileges in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have tried using this SQL code in enabling database creation

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

but it doesn't work.

I have created my phpMyadmin in **Windows Azure Hosting**. I downloaded the latest phpMyadmin from its website and uploaded it to azure now i got this "No Privileges Error".**How can i enable creating new Database?** and also how to fix this command "The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here."
[image: No Privileges]

Answer (score 1):

after your grant statement execute this:

```
flush privileges;
```

Comment: Have you looked through the documentation? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

Answer (score 0):

For the configuration storage, refer to http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage. The doc refers to the current version; for older versions you'll have to look in the scripts folder.